# Update executando múltiplas vezes em uma unica instancia

Tags: php, mysql, query

Tenho tido um problema em meu sistema que algumas paginas que fazem UPDATE nas tabelas de estoque algumas vezes executam múltiplas vezes, entada que a pagina não foi carregada duas vezes pois eu criei uma proteção conta isso. Uma unica instancia mysql_query esta por algum motivo rodando múltiplas vezes no meu MySQL.
 Alguém faz alguma ideia do motivo do bug? Alguém já passou por isso? Eu não estou utilizando PDO, seria uma solução?

Comment: Seria um duplo click o causador isso? Também coloque o código php.

Comment: A função mysql_query será descontinuada. Por que você não publica seu código para que possamos avaliar o problema?

Comment: O certo é você postar o código para que possamos analisar e lhe dar um respaldo a respeito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então, esse problema ocorre em muitos dos meus scripts, eu pensei que era um duplo click ou um refresh ou até mesmo back no histórico, mas eu criei uma proteção contra isso, o mais curioso é que o erro acontece apenas algumas vezes, coisa de uma vez por semana numa pagina que é acessada umas 50 vezes por dia...
 Segue um exemplo do codigo:

//isso contorna o refresh e o click duplo

```
if($_SESSION['DADOS'] != $_REQUEST){
   $sql = "UPDATE estoque SET estoque = (estoque - '" . $_REQUEST['quantidade'] . "') WHERE codigo = '" . $_REQUEST['codigo'] . "'";
   $query = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A Função mysql_COMANDOS está obsoleta, em breve não será mais possível usá-la, até por questões de segurança. A Solução é você usar as funções mysqli_COMANDOS(Esse comandos significa todas as palavras possíveis) ou então fazer a conexão via PDO.